# Elpy - Close Window when invoking elpy-shell-kill

Tags: key-bindings, python, window, shell

Elpy helps a great deal, when editing Python-Code. For example it let's you run the current file with `C-c C-c` in a new Window with a REPL. When i'm done with this, i can hit `C-c C-k (elpy-shell-kill)` to kill the associated shell process.

The process itself gets killed, however, the window stays opened until i manually close it with `C-x k`. Is there a way to close the buffer and let the buffer disappear altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to define your own kill function like:

```
(defun my-kill () 
  (interactive) 
  (elpy-shell-kill-all t) 
  (delete-other-windows))
```

It seems like it would be nice if that worked with a prefix arg, but it doesn't.